# Visibility binding not working on initial start up

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml

I have 2 drop down gallery controls in my project. The choice of the first drop down is what controls what is shown in the second one. I have a couple categories and their visibility is controlled by the enum of the selected item.

```
<RibbonGalleryCategory Header="Slice Attributes" Visibility="{Binding Path=MapModel.SelectedTypeKey, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource EnumMatchToVisibilityConverter}, ConverterParameter={x:Static map1:TypeKey.Slice}}">
```

This works fine except on initial start up. If I change the first drop down the list filters as expected. It shows everything on initial star up and seems to ignore the visibility based on the first drop down. I am using MVVM so I would prefer to not use code behind if I can help it.

Any ideas how I can get the filtering to work on initial start up?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by simulating a property change when your ViewModel is loaded:

Note that you'll also have to call any methods that are normally driven by the event of your drop-down changing.

Example:

```
MapViewModel()
{
     // Do your loads first...        

     NotifyPropertyChange("SelectedTypeKey");
}
```

Comment: That did not seem to work in the constructor. Am I going to have to run it when the actual finished loading event fires?

Comment: Yes, you'll need to make sure everything is loaded first before Notifying.  Look at it as changing changing the selected item in your drop down, then changing it back to the first item.

Comment: @scottlafoy make sure that the view that creates the MV, creates the MV after the screen initialize.

Comment: Still unable to make it work. I have tried many different approaches. I am now trying a code behind solution and I can't even get that to work.

Comment: This should have been a trivial problem. I have killed a day trying solution after solution I have found but still no luck. WPF is really frustrating.